# Get all unique associations in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have and object rides and ride belongs_to company.

I get a list of rides

```
@rides = Ride.where(...)
```

What I need now is to store all companies of those ride in `@companies` where I want to have every company only once, even if two rides have the same company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all **unique** companies of all **rides** as below:

```
@rides = Ride.includes(:company).where(...)

@companies = @rides.map(&:company).uniq
```

**Note:** `includes` will load all companies in single query which are associated to resulting `rides` (prevents N+1 query problem).

Answer (score 0):

PostgresQL is very efficient at doing that kind of work, much more so than Ruby.

You could write:

`@rides = Ride.includes(:company).where(foo: "bar")`

`@companies = @rides.distinct.pluck('companies.name')`

Which will result in the SQL query:

`SELECT DISTINCT companies.name FROM "rides" LEFT OUTER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "rides"."company_id" WHERE (rides.foo IS "bar")`